# how to stop django template code from escaping

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any way to completely turn off django auto_escaping when rendering a template within the view code (for an email for example):

```
from django.template import Context, Template
subject_template_string = "Hi {{ customer.name }}"
subject_template = Template(subject)
context = Context({'customer':MyCustomerModel.objects.get(pk=1)})
subject = subject_template.render(context)
```

If `customer.name` is something like "Jack & Jill" - the subject looks like "Hi Jack &\amp; Jill" (without the backslash!)

is there something like

```
subject = subject_template.render(context, autoescape=False)
```

edit: The actual templates are created by the client in the database, I'm hoping to avoid having to say add `|safe` to all templates where this might happen...

Answer (score 6):

Disabling it globally is usually a bad idea since you can easily forget it. I would recommend using the templatetag to disable it for that portion of your template instead.

Something like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    This will not be auto-escaped: {{ data }}.

    Nor this: {{ other_data }}
    {% autoescape on %}
        Auto-escaping applies again: {{ name }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about using [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

> Explicitly mark a string as safe for (HTML) output purposes. The
>   returned object can be used everywhere a string or unicode object is
>   appropriate.

It marks a string as safe, so, you should take `customer.name` out and pass to the template:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
customer = MyCustomerModel.objects.get(pk=1)
context = Context({'customer_name': mark_safe(customer.name)})
subject = subject_template.render(context)
```

Though, control what is safe or not is better to do inside the template itself, that's why using `autoescape` should be preffered.

Comment: This is a good solution, but would require a lot of editing of clients emails.

Comment: @GuyBowden yeah, thanks, I actually prefer to do the job there I should - for example, use `autoescape` or `safe` in the template. Templates deal with presentation, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Use Django's autoescape tag:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

for more info, check out the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but based on source code review it looks like the context object can take `autoescape` as a key.

```
context = Context({'customer':MyCustomerModel.objects.get(pk=1), 'autoescape': False})
subject = subject_template.render(context)
```

That said, that's a pretty sweeping change.  If you know what values the templates might be looking for, it's probably better to use `mark_safe` on those values and pass in the predefined options.  That would have the added benefit of not risking the possibility of the client template calling a method with side effects on the customer.  The first time someone writes a template and puts in `{{ customer.delete }}`, you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just came back to answer my own question with a simple solution, and there were already 4 answers.. thanks.

This is what I've gone with:

`subject_template = Template(u'{%% autoescape off %%}%s{%% endautoescape %%}' % email.subject)`

Comment: So `email.subject` is itself a string representation of a template?

Comment: Yep - my initial edit alluded to that. The client creates emails in the admin with a subject and body (and has already created a lot) - hence not wanting to have to alter how they were being created.

Comment: In that case that should work, except that it will break if `email.subject` uses the `{% extends %}` tag to inherit from another template.  Which might not be a very likely scenario.